# Java - Função Enter

Tags: java, swing, listener

No sistema existe um campo, a pessoa precisa preencher este campo e em seguida pressionar enter.

Ao pressionar enter o sistema faz uma verificação e em seguida abre um `JOptionpane` pedindo para selecionar: **sim**, **não**, **ok**, etc.

A pessoa aperta com enter, e o sistema executa a função, até ai tudo ok.

O problema é: ao pressionar enter no `JOptionPane` (por exemplo apertei enter no botão **sim**) ele executa novamente a função, só que como não foi preenchido o sistema acaba acusando um erro, ai ele fica no *loop*, porque a pessoa que usa o sistema aperta enter, ai ele carrega novamente, e assim vai...

Como contornar isso? já tentei várias coisas, procurei na internet várias coisas, tudo sem sucesso tem alguma coisa para se fazer para arrumar isso?

Para capturar a ação, estou usando `KeyListener`

**EDIT 1:**

```
 try {

            if (evt.getKeyCode() == 10 || evt.getKeyCode() == 127) {
                jfObjeto.setText(jfObjeto.getText());
                controller.getAtendimentoController().novoAtendimentoItem();
                controller.getAtendimentoController().getAtendimentoModel().getAtendimentoItem().setObjeto(jfObjeto.getText());

            }

            if (evt.getKeyCode() == 10) {
                //verifica se possui sigla cadastrada
                controller.getAtendimentoController().verificaCampoObjeto(
                        controller.getSistemaOperacaoController(),
                        controller.getSistemaSiglaEtiquetaController());
                //verifica se o objeto possui lancamento para EDITAR
                controller.getAtendimentoController().consultaObjetoEdicao();
                if (controller.getAtendimentoController().getAtendimentoModel().getAtendimentoItem().getId() > 0) {
                    int resposta = new Mensagem().pergunta("Atenção deseja alterar o objeto " + controller.getAtendimentoController().getAtendimentoModel().getAtendimentoItem().getObjeto() + "?");
                    if (resposta == 0) {
                        preencherAtendimentoItemToFrame();
                    }
                }
                 // avanca para proximo campo, ou recua para o anterior

                formatarAvancarRecuarAtendimentoItem(evt, jfObjeto);

            } else if (evt.getKeyCode() == 127) {
                controller.getAtendimentoController().consultaObjetoEdicao();
                if (controller.getAtendimentoController().getAtendimentoModel().getAtendimentoItem().getId() > 0) {
                    int resposta = new Mensagem().pergunta("Deseja excluir o objeto " + controller.getAtendimentoController().getAtendimentoModel().getAtendimentoItem().getObjeto() + "?");
                    if (resposta == 0) {
                        controller.getAtendimentoController().excluirObjetoPostagemItem();
                        controller.getAtendimentoController().carregarListaAtendimentoItem();
                        tabelaAtendimentoItem();
                        limparAtendimentoItem();
                        carregarQuantidadeValorTotalAtendimento();
                        controller.getAtendimentoController().novoAtendimentoItem();
                        jfObjeto.requestFocusInWindow();
                    }
                } else {
                    new Mensagem().erro("Nenhum Objeto Localizado para Exclusão");
                }

            } else if (evt.getKeyCode() == 27) {
                formatarAvancarRecuarAtendimentoItem(evt, jfObjeto);
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            new Mensagem().erro(ex.getMessage());
            jfObjeto.requestFocusInWindow();
        }
```

Comment: Poste o código do `KeyListener` para podermos te ajudar.

Comment: Não seria mais fácil deixar abrir o tal JOPTIONPANE só e só se o campo necessário( `No sistema existe um campo, a pessoa precisa preencher este campo e em seguida pressionar enter.` ) for diferente de `null` ou `vazio` etc :)

Comment: Não entendo da tecnologia mas minha primeira ideia seria mudar o foco para algum outro lugar antes de abrir o PANE.

Comment: for diferente de null ou vazio etc :) - Se for null a mensagem informa que o usuario precisa prencher esse campo.... ai ele fica apertando enter toda hora e entra no loop q eu falei....

Comment: cai no mesmo erro, eu tiro o foco executo o comando no final ele recebe o foco novamente para o usuario digitar outras informações... vai cair no loop eterno....o problema é no ENTER que a pessoa da no JOPTION PANE, ali devido a esse enter ele entra no loop infinito.....                                   EDIT: eu preciso da tecla, pois o enter tem uma funcao... o esc tem outra funcao... a tecla delete tem oura funcao... nao da para ser isso tb

Comment: Há a possibilidade de inserir o source do KeyListener?

Comment: esta inserido no keyListener... o codigo que eu coloquei está la.... pois o enter tem uma funcao... o esc tem outra funcao... a tecla delete tem oura funcao e eu preciso capturar o evento....

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 1):

você pode trabalhar com threads uma para os eventos e outra para a tela
então :

```
if(evt.getKeyCode()== com.sun.glass.events.KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){

            tela.wait(timeout);
 }
```

Comment: desculpa a minha ignorância, mas como eu vou fazer para fazer essa separação?

Comment: No seu sistema você vai fazer uma thread que controla a interface e outra que controla as teclas quando usuário fizer uma ação com as teclas você da um wait() na tela e executa o código na  thread das teclas.

Comment: a minha dúvida é, para fazer o sistema eu utilizo o Netbeans, quando vai ser executado ele chama java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        }); como que eu vou fazer para pausar essa thread?

Answer (score 0):

Utilize uma variável global de controle, assim você consegue verificar se não é a segunda vez que o <kbd>ENTER</kbd> está sendo apertado. Logo após a execução no `JOptionpane` mude novamente para o valor padrão e o problema estará resolvido.

Por exemplo:

```java
private Boolean respondendo = false;

private void verificarTeclas(KeyEvent evt) {
  Integer resposta;

  if (!respondendo) {
    System.out.println("Tecla " + String.valueOf(evt.getKeyCode()) + " sendo analisada");
    this.respondendo = true;

    if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
      resposta = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Deseja excluir o objeto?");

      if (resposta == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
        // Faz o sim;
      } else {
        // Faz o não
      }
    }

    this.respondendo = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Não vejo como isso pode resolver este problema. Adicione um exemplo para que fique claro.